# Why Can I Convert Leads in Classic but not in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, lead-conversion, salesforce-classic

- System Administrator Profile with Convert Leads, and full access to accounts/contacts/opportunities

On the classic page I can see the "Convert" button and it opens the lead conversion page, where I can convert a lead.  In lightning I cannot see the convert button.  When I move the sales process to the Converted status at the end, it does not give me the full conversion page and I get an alert indicating that the lead is not converted.

This is in a sandbox, in production (same lead, same account) I can convert using either method.  I don't see any difference in settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the "Convert" button to the "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions" by selecting the button from "Mobile & Lightning Actions" section on the page layout for this to work in Lightning Experience. Refer to the image below.

[image]